I want to fix a problem regarding import plotly in vs code
I am encountering an error while running import plotly within VS Code Notebook. While when I run the same command within python file it runs perfectly.
The error which appears when I run within the VS Code notebook as follows:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

I tried to uninstall plotly and install it again, re-install python and uninstall anaconda environment.
I want import plotly in notebook without problems.

This was usually caused by incorrect python interpreter and jupyter kernel.
You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the correct python interpreter which you installed the plotly in. And then click the jupyter kernel button to change the kernel.

Read document for more details about jupyter-notebook.
